# Remotely executing a memory intensive exe with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to kick off an exe (it was written in house) using powershell. The exe is memory intensive, using 12 - 15 gigs at times (it's an overnight job) The exe works fine and it's been moved to it's own machine with 32 gigs of RAM. Rather than use WINAT or something to schedule it, I'd like to use powershell to centralize where all the nightly processes are run from and execute it remotely. However, I keep running into memory issues (from what my searching around has shown). I'm getting this message on the calling machine - "The WS Man process did not return a proper response. A provider in the host may have behaved improperly." So I started changing the value of MaxMemoryPerShell and I could get the exe to start sometimes, though I've yet to get it to finish. This is the setting I'm referring to:

Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB

I've tried setting that to 15 gigs on the target machine and had no luck. Does anyone have any experience calling memory intensive processes with powershell? I'm not clear as to what maxmemory should be set to, which machines it needs to be set on, or if there's other settings I'm not aware of.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: Here is the call I'm using in powershell:

`invoke-command -ComputerName targetmachine.mydomain.com -Scriptblock{cd "D:\Code";.\MyProcess.exe N 30}`

"N" and 30 and parameters passed into the exe.

Comment: Can you hop on the remote machine and observe the wsmprovhost.exe process and see if it is getting anywhere near 15GBs?  Have the remote script output the $pid variable so you know what the process id is on the remote machine.  Perhaps it needs 16GB or there is something different going on if it is not getting close to that limit.

Comment: Please post code on how do you start the remote process. Use `Start-Process` if you don't already, so that your Powershell session won't grow.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the code I'm using to call the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PSEXEC, works like a champ. No memory issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the value of `WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB` is not enough. You also need to update that value in a plugin configuration. So the following script helped me to increase the maximum allowed memory usage by "Host process for WinRM plug-ins" (`wsmprovhost.exe`) to 8GB on a target machine:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 8192
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 8192
Restart-Service WinRM
```